# What happens with global/singleton objects when using ECS?

Tags: c++, input, design-patterns, entity-component-system

As I've been learning about ECS one thing that gets me confused are things like input which in my case has usually been some singleton that gets polled or in one project was event based where code can listen to a key/action anyways with ECS do I just do

```
void SomeControllerSystem::update(ECS& ecs, float timestep) {
    for (auto& entity : ecs.queryEntitiesWith<PlayerComponent, TransformComponent>()) {
        PlayerComponent& player = ecs.getComponent<PlayerComponent>(entity);
        TransformComponent& transform = ecs.getComponent<TransformComponent>(entity);

        if (Input::IsKeyDown(SDLK_w)) {
            // Update transform component?
        }
    }
}
```

Or do I have to make some changes to integrate into ECS? A few things that I stumbled across are singleton entities/components which I think I originally heard [from that overwatch gdc video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3aieHjyNvw), but I don't really understand what that means.

Also, unrelated, but can components have basic logic?  For example

```
struct CameraComponent {
    // data ...
    void GetProjectionMatrix();
    void GetViewMatrix()
};
```

That doesn't really count as logic right?

Comment: About your second question, these appear to be handy getters, there to make your life easier. You can do that when you have to "convert" data held by your component to multiple needs.

Answer (score 2):

The way I have solved "input" in an ECS is that I have a ComponentController that I stick to the Player entity (so I call it ComponentControllerPlayer). This component contains "what the input was" and there is a System that knows how to convert "what the input was" to "what the input means in terms of gameplay". This System will know a lot about how the entity is being composed (e.g. you control a car, then the system will assume one car body and four wheels, of which the 2 front wheels can steer and the 2 rear wheels cannot).

The Singleton that checks the input will update the ComponentControllerPlayer every frame, then this data will be consumed by the system.

This way you can either use an actual input scheme (like I describe above), or you can have your input dictated by another "System" like a robot/AI that is update upstream and reacts to the world.

---

That being said, and I'll repeat myself, there is no ECS police. Do the thing that works the best for your, then when you hit a snag, fix it *at that moment*, you'll know what the issue you're trying to fix is, and so that'll be the time to figure the best appropriate solution.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly you have one system that populates the controller with input then another system would just do something based on the input in the controller?

Comment: That's one way to see this, yes. Although in our app, "Systems" are generally things that handle environment/simulation stuff, so the "input" don't technically come from a "system", it comes from a "manager". But that's specific for our situation. If you want to see them both as Systems, that's fine too.

Answer (score 1):

In ECS, Input handling typically isn't directly integrated into the core ECS architecture since it's considered external to the game world simulation. Instead, you would handle input separately using your existing input handling mechanism - be it a singleton, event-based, or another method.

Comment: how would events work in this situation? Say I were to use the observer pattern (that's all I know when it comes to event based stuff lol) I assume I'd just make my systems an observer?

Comment: @Konjointed It depends on the events, and how easily you want to read your code. If some parts of your ECS poll events while it does not make sense for other parts, differing patterns may make your code base harder to follow.